# How would you select versions from a specific branch in ClearCase?

Tags: configuration, clearcase

I would like to get all the files checked-in a private branch and only the those files checked in.

What config spec would you recommend?

Let's say `prvt` is the private branch:

```
element * .../prvt/LATEST
```

Would that work?

---

What if I want to load only those elements which are branched out only in prvt branch not any other element as I suppose

```
element /myVob/myPath /main/LATEST
element /myVob /main/LATEST
```

might get files which branch out from the main latest also in myPath directory.
But this is very much useful only for directories as I wouldn't have branched out the directories of the checked in file element in the private branch

Answer (score 3):

This will only work if every element has a prvt branch.

So if your files are in `/myVob/myPath`, the config spec

```
element * .../prvt/LATEST
```

will select the right versions (those in LATEST of prvt branch), only if /myVob has a prvt branch (i.e. has already been checked out / checked in in that branch), *and* if `myPath` has a `prvt` branch.
**If the leading path has no `prvt` branch, no version will be selected**, meaning the files within that path won't have a chance to be selected by your selection rule.
That is the real issue here.

That is why I recommend adding some stopping rules:

```
element * .../prvt/LATEST
element /myVob/myPath /main/LATEST
element /myVob /main/LATEST
```

That way, within `/myVob/myPath`, only the right versions are shown, but for the path *leading** to those files, you have at least backup config spec rules which allows you to at least select one version.

If you know the branch from which `prvt` branch has been done, using that branch name would be safer.
If you don't '`/main/LATEST`' is a sure bet, since the `main` branch always exists.

Answer (score 0):

the best way I found out to do this task was:

```
cleartool find . -version "brtype(BRANCH_NAME) && version(\main\VIEW_NAME\BRANCH_NAME\1)" -print
```

Yes, I know, \1 in the end will only return the first version, but that's ok, by doing this, you already know every single file you have checked-in, at least once.