# How to find Branch name of clearcase view

Tags: clearcase

How can we find the branch name to which my ClearCase view is pointed to?

Comment: I took the liberty to remove your signature: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28416/what-is-the-policy-on-signatures-and-links-in-answers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The thing is, a view doesn't point to *one* branch.
It only combines various element selection rules in the config spec, which makes it reflect a version on a branch at a given time, for a given tree/file.
See:

- [How would you select versions from a specific branch in ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296930/how-would-you-select-versions-from-a-specific-branch-in-clearcase/3297002#3297002) for a concrete example.
- [How best to branch in Clearcase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996274/how-best-to-branch-in-clearcase/997607#997607) to see how branches work.

See also the debate on [selection by composition vs. selection by revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763099/flexible-vs-static-branching-git-vs-clearcase-accurev/764219#764219) to better understand why, by default, a ClearCase config spec doesn't necessary reference one branch.

The simpler way to check what is the *current* branch is:

- `cd /my/view/path/to/relevant/directory`
- `cleartool ls`

Example:

```
C:\views\myView\path\to\dir>cleartool ls
.checkstyle@@\main\MY_BRANCH_Dev\4                         Rule: ...\MY_BRANCH_Dev\LATEST
.classpath@@\main\MY_BRANCH_Int\ADV_ACC_Dev\1              Rule: ...\MY_BRANCH_Dev\LATEST
.classycle@@\main\MY_BRANCH_Int\ADV_ACC_Dev\0              Rule: ...\MY_BRANCH_Dev\LATEST
```

That view, for the `path/to/relevant/directory` path, point to branch `MY_BRANCH_Dev`

---

Note: With ClearCase UCM, this is simpler:

```
cleartool lsstream -cview
```

will give you the name of the name of the Stream (and by extension, the associated branch) on which the views points to.

Comment: Hi Von, say if I want to know the list of branches the clearcase view is pointed to?

Comment: @srinannapa Unless you are using UCM, the simplest way is to extract the branch names from the config spec (`cleartool catcs`)

Answer (score 0):

Von is correct.

However, to understand the branching selection for base clearcase, it is better to learn how the Config Specs works.

cleartool man edcs, and read the config_specs documentation.