# ClearCase checkout version not selected by config spec

Tags: clearcase

From a snapshot view using base ClearCase, I want to checkout the latest version of a file from a branch that is NOT selected in my snapshot view. I would expect this to be possible, because you can do it from the version tree browser tool.

However, [the documentation for the `checkout` command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_checkout.htm) claims that you can't do this in a snapshot (emphasis mine): [**edit:** Yes you can! See below.]

> Nonstandard checkouts
>
> By default, the checkout command checks out
>   these versions:
>
> - The most recent version on a branch, if you are using a dynamic view
> - The version currently loaded in the view, if you are using a snapshot view
>
> To modify a different version, you can either use the –version option or create a subbranch at that version. (See the mkbranch
>   reference page). Furthermore, from a single view, you can have only
>   one checkout per element at a time.
>
> Note: When you work in a **snapshot** view, the only version of a
>   directory element that can be checked out is the version currently
>   loaded in the view. Therefore, the **–version and –branch options do not
>   work.**

How can I check out an unselected version from the command line?

---

[**edit:** Here I misread the "Note:" section. What the help means is that **directories** can't be checked out using the `-version` or `-branch` args, but normal files can be.]

Comment: You can always set your config spec to that branch

Comment: Yeah I could. I want to create a script that checks out several files from another branch, makes some automated modifications to those files, and then checks them in on a different branch. If this has to be done by updating my config spec, that would be pretty annoying. But it may be the only way :(

Comment: I really don't think you can check out from a branch that's not in your view.. maybe there is a way but I have never seen that in my normal workflow.

Comment: @0A0D - If you're using windows, open the version tree browser for a file. Right click some node that is not selected by your current spec. There, I see an option "Check out..." as the first item in the menu.

Comment: Interesting, never had to try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual solution selected by the [OP dss539](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55721/dss539) is to use `cleartool checkout` directly (see [`cleartool checkout` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_checkout.htm))

```
cleartool checkout -bra/nch branch-pname | -ver/sion
```

It would work for files (not directories) in dynamic *or snapshot* view.

---

If you don't want to modify the config spec of your current snapshot file, then you can:

- either use a separate view (a dynamic one in order to have the right version immediately selected), and modify at will the config spec of *that other* (dynamic view),
  And copy the version back to your snapshot view.
  See also "[How would you select versions from a specific branch in ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3297002/6309)" for config spec example.
  ...
  Actually, you don't even need to modify the config spec of that dynamic view:
  You can use the [**extended pathname** of the version you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987427/why-cant-perl-find-my-file-that-is-in-clearcase/988904#988904) to directly access and copy the right version.
- or use the [`cleartool get`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_get.htm) command (which is what "Send To" is doing on the version Tree).
  See "[clearcase command to backup predecessor version of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5381646/6309)"
  (You don't need a separate view here)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and accept if it works for me. You mention the "Send To" in the version tree, but what about the "Check out..."? Does it also use a `cleartool get`?

Comment: btw - thanks for your many other ClearCase posts on SO. They're all very helpful!

Comment: If it uses `cleartool checkout`, how does it get the version that is not currently selected by the view?

Comment: @dss539 because it checks out the same **extended pathname** I mention in my answer. Look at your config spec (`cleartool catcs`): the *first* rule is: `element * CHECKEDOUT`. So once any version is checked out, it is selected by that first rule. On checking, there will be a merge with the LATEST version in order to create a new LATEST version.

Comment: Hmm. Ok so **extended pathname** does, in fact, work in snapshot views. I thought that it did not, due to my misreading of the CC help. So that means I can checkout files on any branch without having a separate view of config spec. I'll edit my question to highlight the part I misread.

Comment: @dss539 yes, if you want to *copy* an extended pathname, you need a dynamic view, but if you want to checkout, you can do so from *any* view.