# How do I check out a specific version of a file in clearcase?

Tags: clearcase, version-tree

## Background

In clearcase, I have a dev version tree for a file that looks like this:

(1)

|

(2)

|

(3)

When I run a certain program, it hangs up on an error that is in version (1) of the file. It will not look at other versions because my program is tied to a certain label.  Therefore, I want to make an unreserved checkout of version (1) and fix the error.

## Problem

When I run the command `ct co -unreserved -nmaster -nc filename`, it checks out the file in version 3 not version 1.

## Question

How do I checkout version (1) of the file and make changes in that version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [checkout a version which is not selected by the config spec of your view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16219205/6309), using [`cleartool checkout`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/fi/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_checkout.htm)

> Check out an old version of the file hello.h, using an extended path name to indicate the version. (Before you check in your revised version, you must perform a merge.)

```
cleartoolt checkout -un -nm -c "attempt fix of old bug" -version hello.h@@\main\1
```

> With `-nmaster`, checks out the branch even if the current replica does not master the branch. Do not use this option if you cannot merge versions of the element.

It would work for files (not directories) in dynamic or snapshot view.